# How can I get the text of the selected Radio Button without to use the if clause?

Tags: c#, events

I have aq Windows Forms application with a variable large number of Radio Buttons (50+).
I have an event handler for all the Radio Buttons:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == (RadioButton)radioButton1)
    {
         selectedItem = radioButton1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
         selectedItem = radioButton2.Text;
    }
}
```

That works fine for two Radio Buttons.
How can I get the text of the selected Radio Button without to use the if clause?
Thank you iin advance,
Paul

Comment: `selectedItem = ((RadioButton)sender).Text;`

Comment: I do not know which of the 50+ Radio Buttons has been selected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this; but you also need to check if it's [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) because the event fires when a radio button is de-checked as well, [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast and store for future use.
    var senderRadioButton = (RadioButton)sender; 

    //check if sender is checked
    if (senderRadioButton.Checked)
        selectedItem = senderRadioButton.Text;

    //else
}
```

Make sure you wire all your changed events to this handler.